# Import and cut (grid) satellite image via Python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, classification, satellite-image, landsat

Can you help me with this?

I need to know which Python code (library / package) allows me to download Landsat 8 image (a specific orbit / point) directly from Earth Explorer.

---

AND, ALSO, I will take only 3 (three) cutouts of 270 x 270 Landsat 8 scene (do you know how to make this cut directly by Python?)

It’s because I need to do an image classification using CNNs (I am using Jupyter notebooks).